# How to convert a native binary image in memory to an Winforms Image?

Tags: winforms, image, c++-cli, native

I have a native c++ library that creates an output image as a native area in memory. It's ARGB, 32bit for one pixel, width*height times. I have a winforms application where I want to display this output image. Therefore I added a picturebox which needs the Image-property set to an Image. How do I convert this?

Sidenote: I had a similar issue some time ago with a WPF app displaying such an image. I got that working like this:

```
BitmapSource ^ bitmap = BitmapSource::Create(pic->GetX(), pic->GetY(),
        96, 96, PixelFormats::Bgr32, nullptr,
        IntPtr(pic->GetPointer()), pic->GetX() * pic->GetY() * sizeof(unsigned int), pic->GetX() * sizeof(unsigned int));
ImageControl->Source = bitmap;
```

where pic->GetPointer() returns the native pointer to the image in memory. But this doesn't work for Winforms.

Comment: We don't use bbcode tags here. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Use Bitmap.LockBits() to get a pointer to the pixel data.

Comment: Take a look at the BitmapData class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspx

Comment: Ok thank you all. I now user LockBits() and memcpy the data in there. I'm not sure if it's as efficient as the BitmapSource approach I can use in WPF - I guess it doesn't copy the picture - but it works for me. :) And sorry for the bbcode tags.

Comment: Now we have an answer, but nobody posted it as an answer. What should we do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Adapting from comments:</sub>

Use [Bitmap.LockBits()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits.aspx) to get a pointer to the pixel data, and take a look at the [BitmapData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspx) class in general.